# Minimum variance for investment portfolio problem

Tags: statistics, finance, economics

> Suppose you wish to invest a fixed sum of money in to assets that yield returns of $X$ and $Y$, where $X$, and $Y$ are random quantities. You will invest a fraction $a$ in $X$ and the remaining in $Y$. Because there is variability associated with the returns on these two assets we wish to choose $a$ such that the total risk or variance is minimized. We want to minimize $\mathbb{Var}(aX+(1-a)Y)$.
>
> Find $a$ such that the risk is minimized.

Here's what I have gotten till so far:
$$
a^2 \mathbb{Var}[X]+(1-a)^2 \mathbb{Var}[Y]+a(1-a)\mathbb{E}{[X-\mathbb{E}(X)][Y-\mathbb{E}(Y)]}
$$

What's the next step for finding the minimum variance? Which terms should be expanded and how can they be rearranged together?

Comment: What is the distribution for your random variables? You would need that to proceed forward

Comment: The question doesn't specify anything so its safe to assume they are both normally distributed

Comment: I interpret that the expression that you have written is equal to the variance of the total yields. That is the expression that we want to minimise. The only variable we can change ourselves is $a$, so it's natural that we want to find the value of $a$ that minimises that expression. Therefore, we might want to find the derivative of the expression and set that to zero. But obviously, as we see from the expression, the answer will include terms like $\mathbb{E}[X], \mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\mathbb{Var}[X], \mathbb{Var}[Y]$. So in order to get a numerical answer, we will need these values.

Comment: By the way, could it be so that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$ or something similar?

Comment: Notice also the symmetry in the problem: If we know nothing about $X$ and $Y$, we can just switch up the names and the problem is still exactly the same. So if we have an expression for the variance, something like
$$
\mathbb{Var}=f(a)
$$
Then, due to symmetry, it has to be so that
$$
f(a) = f(1-a)
$$, no?

Comment: @MattiP. the scope of the question is such that the exact numerical answer is not needed, the answer in terms of other variables would also be expected.

Comment: Updated OP to incorporate further steps.

Answer (score 1):

The variance is
$$\text{Var}(aX+(1-a)Y) = a^2 \text{Var}(X) + (1-a)^2 \text{Var}(Y) + 2a(1-a) \text{Cov}(X,Y).$$
This is a quadratic of the form
$$c_2 a^2 + c_1 a + c_0$$
with
\begin{align}
c_2 &= \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) - 2 \text{Cov}(X,Y)
\\
c_1 &= -2 \text{Var}(Y)  + 2\text{Cov}(X,Y)
\\
c_0 &= \text{Var}(Y)
\end{align}

If $c_2 < 0$, then this is a $\cap$-shaped quadratic, which will be minimized either at $a=0$ or $a=1$, depending on which of $\text{Var}(X)$ or $\text{Var}(Y)$ is smaller.

If $c_2 = 0$, then this is a line, will be minimized either at $a=0$ or $a=1$.

If $c_2 > 0$, then this is a $\cup$-shaped quadratic, which is minimized at $-\frac{c_1}{2c_2} = \frac{\text{Var}(Y) - \text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) - 2 \text{Cov}(X,Y)}$ if this quantity is between $0$ and $1$; otherwise it is again minimized either at $a=0$ or $a=1$.

Comment: How do you get 2a in the third term? There is only one a that's taken common out of `X` and `E(X)`.

Comment: And in the generic quadratic form you have written, where did `1-a` go?

Comment: @atastix The factor of two comes from $a(X-E[X]) (1-a) (Y-E[Y]) + (1-a)(Y-E[Y]) a (X - E[X])$. The coefficients $c_i$ come from expanding everything, including $(1-a)^2 = 1-2a+a^2$.